# Direct product of rings: what makes the product fail to receive natural ring homomrophisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

I started out some review of math by doing abstract algebra and I do not know enough about canonical morphisms to explain this: a "ring homomorphism" $R \rightarrow R \times S$ which sends $r$ to $(r,0)$ is not a ring homomorphism because it fails to send $1$ to $(1,1)$ assuming that $0 \neq 1$. I would like to know what makes it fail to send the identity element $1$ to the identity element $(1,1)$ if it is a canonical ring homomorphism. How's that mean the product does not receive natural ring homomorphisms?

Comment: Your question is highly unclear. What is $r$? Which map are you talking about? The constant map which sends each element of $r$ to $(0, 1)$? What is a "canonical ring homomorphism"? What makes you think that the map you defined, whatever it is, is a "canonical ring homomorphism", whatever that is?

Comment: Well im near sighted and I couldnt read that clearly, I guess since It says it sends the element r to r,0 it wouldn't be able to send r to r,1 or 1 to 1,1. Only 1 to 1,0...

Comment: @mattstokes Are you sure about $r \mapsto (r,1)$? It is not even an additive map.

Comment: @azif00 Thanks! Deleted my comment.

Comment: I guess it depends on your definitions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism#Non-examples says "Given a product of rings $S=R_{1}\times R_{2}$, the natural inclusion $R_{1}\to S,x\mapsto (x,0)$ is not a ring homomorphism (unless $R_{2}$ is the zero ring); this is because the map does not send the multiplicative identity of $R_{1}$ to that of $S$, namely $(1,1)$."

Answer (score 2):

After you fix up the typoze... I think you will find that your issue exactly that commented-upon by @GerryMyerson: for most purposes, we *want* a ring homomorphism $R\to S$ (rings with units!)to send $1_R\to 1_S$. This does *not* follow merely from preserving additive and multiplicative structures... so it is possible to *drop* that condition... and have "rng" homomorphisms, but lots of desirable features break then. So we want to require $1_R\to 1_S$.

For some perspective, the *product* $R\times S$ of two commutative rings *is* the cartesian product, with projection maps $p:(r,s)\to r$ and $q:(r,s)\to s$. And this has the universal property that, for any two commutative ring homs $f:T\to R$ and $g:T\to S$, there is a ring hom $F:T\to R\times S$ such that $p\circ F=f$ and $q\circ F=g$. Namely, $F(t)=(f(t),g(t))$.

In the vein of universal properties, the coproduct/direct sum of two commutative rings does exist, though it's not the product. It's the tensor product $R\otimes_{\mathbb Z} S$. The map $i:R\to R\otimes_{\mathbb Z} S$ is $i(r)=r\otimes 1$, and the map $j:S\to R\otimes_{\mathbb Z} S$ by $j(s)=1\otimes s$. This has the expected universal property (reversing the arrows in the description of the property of the product), namely, for every pair of maps $f:R\to T$ and $g:S\to T$, there is a unique $F:R\otimes_{\mathbb Z} S\to T$ such that $F\circ i=f$ and $F\circ j=g$. Namely, $F(r\otimes s)=f(r)g(s)$.