# Natural morphism/s: The morphism doesn't preserve identity elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra

[$r \mapsto (r,0)$ is the natural map 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4484996/direct-product-of-rings-what-makes-the-product-fail-to-receive-natural-ring-hom)

[$r \mapsto (r,0)$ is the natural map 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism#Non-examples)

Considering the two rings $R$ and $R \times R$ the ring morphism $r \mapsto (r,0)$ is not a ring homomorphism, but it's also the natural homomorphism. Why does it preserve the additive identity instead of the multiplicative identity or instead of both identities?

Comment: If we drop the unital structure of the rings, then the maps between rings do not need to preserve the multiplicative identity (i.e. the $1$). But usually if are considering *unital* rings specifically, then we want $1\mapsto 1$, so these natural maps would not be *unital* ring homomorphisms (they are module maps, however).

Comment: So the natural morphism is the one between the underlying sets not between structures?

Comment: It's a morphism with respect to more than just the set structure, e.g. the module or *nonunital* ring structure. But it is not a morphism with respect to the *unital* ring structure.

Comment: What is it about preserving both identities that isn't possible if its a canonical morphism though?

Comment: the thing is that rings have an additive and a multiplicative structure, in particular $R\times S$ is actually not the coproduct, but the product which comes with canonical PROJECTIONS not INJECTIONS. Those are $(r,s)\to r$ and $(r,s)\to s$. The injections are just the structure morphism of the direct sum (product and coproduct) in abelian groups after applying the forgetful functor. The issue is in the end that in the cat of Rings, the coproduct is the tensor product and the product is the set theoretic product.